# Deleting files from heroku repo manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I want to delete some files from heroku repository using command line and without pushing the codes, is it possible? I'm unable to push to heroku due to some precompilation error.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Heroku does not allow shell access and is designed for all files to be controlled solely through git push. You'd be better off posting a question about your precompilation error, I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change what's running in your dyno is to create a new release, and you can currently only do that by pushing a new release. I'm afraid you'll have to fix the precompilation problem or remove the precompile step.